# Using music in a java program

Tags: java, audio, wmv

I was trying out the method of creating a background music for a java program, but it displayed an IO excedption error when i clicked the play button.

```
package javaentertainment;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.*;
import sun.audio.AudioData;
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;

public class Music
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(100,100);
        JButton button=new JButton("P L A Y");
        frame.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new AL());
        frame.show();
    }

   public static class AL implements ActionListener
   {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            music();
        }
    }

    public static void music()
    {
        AudioPlayer MGP=AudioPlayer.player;
        AudioStream BGM;
        AudioData MD;
        ContinousAudioDataStream loop=null;

        try
        {
            BGM = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream("Vision.wmv"));
            MD=BGM.getData();
            loop=new ContinousAudioDataStream(MD);

        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
           System.out.println(ex);
        }

        MGP.start(loop); // word loop was underlined by netbeans
    }
}
```

When I run the program and click on play it displays the following error,
java.io.IOException: could not create audio stream from input stream

Comment: Please indent your code by 4 spaces, to make the imports readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use JMF (Java Media Framework). For your interest: The list of accepted formats can be found [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/formats.html).

In short, it supports AIFF, AVI, GSM, MVR, MID, MPG, MP2, MOV, AU and WAV files.

But there is a workarond as stated [here](http://archives.java.sun.com/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind0204&L=jmf-interest&D=1&P=25378):

> On a side note, if you add a
>   mime-setting in JMFRegistry to map
>   Windows Media content (such as .asf
>   and .wmv) to the content-type
>   "video/mpeg", JMF can actually play
>   Windows Media or any other DirectShow
>   file (and only file - http wont work).

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised if Java can hand Windows Media format samples - try converting the .wmv to a .wav file and see if it works then.

Comment: Well now the previous error is ok but it displays 

java.io.IOException: could not create AudioData object

Answer (score 0):

Just got this, as well.

```
java.io.IOException: could not create AudioData object
```

Appears from the source [1] that this means that "your audio file is size > 1 MB" and it doesn't like that for whatever reason.  Maybe a bug [?] that they don't accomodate for this.

One work-around might be to use JMF instead, as suggested, if you want looping to work for large files anyway.

[1] http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/audio/AudioStream.html#getData