# Looping Music in Java

Tags: java, swing, audio, javasound

I'm trying to get this program to loop the song infinitely, but I've only managed to get it working once. Any advice?

Here is my code:

```
public static void music(){

    String filename = "darkAura.wav";
    ContinuousAudioDataStream loop = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(filename);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
    try {
        AudioStream s = new AudioStream(in);
        AudioData MD;
        AudioPlayer.player.start(s);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: Please have a look at [Looping audio on separate thread in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255162/looping-audio-on-separate-thread-in-java/23255259#comment35586476_23255259) that is posted in the same context. Find the answer in the question itself.

Comment: Is the code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23250089/877472) of any use?

Comment: No. This, after adjusting, simply makes the sound stop. The moment I use a timer, it doesn't work.

Comment: Use the [Java Sound](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) based `Clip`.  The linked page has an example of looping a sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using `loop` variable at all.
Try it like this:

```
AudioStream s = new AudioStream(in);     
AudioData audiodata = s.getData();
loop = new ContinuousAudioDataStream(audiodata);
AudioPlayer.player.start(loop);
```

Comment: Where is `loop` declared?

Comment: In his code: `ContinuousAudioDataStream loop = null;`

Comment: The ContinuousAudioDataStream doesn't work. When I try the solution above, I get this:

could not create AudioData object

Comment: one possible workaround is to use official sound API as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676723/could-not-create-audiodata-object or use JMF as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274775/using-music-in-a-java-program
Also playing with file size may help, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676723/could-not-create-audiodata-object

Comment: So far, I've not been able to use any of them to loop the .wav file. I can't get the JMF import to work, I can't change the file size, and the API solution simply just didn't work. :/ Overall, I think I'm just going to give up on it.

Comment: Braj's comment to your answer might do the job - if you have managed to play the audio once, perhaps looping it in a while loop will work, though there may be tiny gap on before the next repetition, you would have to try.
Also for JMF to work you have to include proper libraries in your project, but for that you would have to consult other thread, perhaps [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16163731/3356028) if using Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Braj's made it mute. And I've looked into JMF before it. Normally posting here is a last resort. I just can't seem to find the proper file, or if I have found it, how to set it up. :/ Suppose that might just because I'm a noobish college student.